# awk opens Pipe Separated Value file with data in a single column, not three

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a [PSV](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values) file test1.psv with three columns of data as below, when opened by [awk](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/awk.1posix.html), shows data in a single column.

```
xxxx|0001|rose  
yyyy|8768|lotus  
fgsh|6543|lilly
```

actually this should be the "|" delimited file with 3 columns, but when I `print $1`, all the columns comes as first column as below

```
cat test1.psv |awk '{print $1}'
```

outputs:

```
xxxx|0001|rose
yyyy|8768|lotus
fgsh|6543|lilly
```

but the result should be:

```
xxxx
yyyy
fgsh
```

if we `print $2`, result should be:

```
0001
8768
6543
```

Comment: That character is vertical line. Pipe is just one of its uses. It is not used as a pipe here, therefore not a pipe.

Answer (score 4):

You have to set a field separator to `|` with `-F` like that (also,
you don't need `cat`):

```
$ awk -F '|' '{print $1}' test1.csv
xxxx
yyyy
fgsh
$ awk -F '|' '{print $2}' test1.csv
0001
8768
6543
$ awk -F '|' '{print $3}' test1.csv
rose
lotus
lillyw
```

(Notice that `$` here is a [command line
prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt)
used to indicate start of a new line, not a part of the command).

`-F` is specified by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) and should be portable.

Answer (score 2):

[awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html) will assume a file is separated tabs or a string of one or more spaces, so to use a Pipe Separated Value file, we tell awk our fields are separated by the vertical bar character | .

From the first link in the sentence above:

The value of (the field separator)  can be changed in the awk program with the assignment operator, ‘=’ (see section Assignment Expressions). Often, the right time to do this is at the beginning of execution before any input has been processed, so that the very first record is read with the proper separator. To do this, use the special BEGIN pattern (see section The BEGIN and END Special Patterns).

For example, here we set the value of (the field separator, aka **FS**) to the string "|":

```
cat test1.psv | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" } ; { print $1 }'
```

Comment: The default field separator that `awk` uses is not the comma but any stretch of consecutive whitespace (tabs or spaces).

Comment: OP started with "CSV" in the original post, then changed to "PSV". Some days, it's all I can do to keep the straps on my straitjacket tight, but I'll fix that shortly.

Comment: "PSV" is something they invented themselves. Most CSV parsers (e,g, `csvkit`) can be used with an arbitrary field separator character.

Comment: Yep, but other folks invented the same thing:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966203/reading-psv-pipe-separated-file-or-string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904613/what-is-the-accepted-file-extension-to-use-for-pipe-delimited-files et al.

Comment: It is not a pipe in this context. I standardised on BSV implying Bar. For bonus obfuscation points, try using UTF-8 (302 246) "Broken Bar".

Answer (score 0):

to simply return only a particular column of a delimited file issue this

```
cut -d'|' -f1 test1.csv
```

to return the field 1 ... change above to -f2 to return the 2nd column ...   the -d parm defines the delimiter character in this case '|'

its common to create a pipeline of many commands linked together using the pipe  |   so above can also be written

```
cat test1.csv | cut -d'|' -f1
```

Comment: No need to use `cat` in the second example neither.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F "|" '{print $1}' p.txt ===============> To get first column

awk -F "|" '{print $2}' p.txt===================> To get second column




python

Below python code drives first and second column

#!/usr/bin/python

k=open('p.txt','r')
for i in k:
    print " ".join(i.split("|")[0:2])
```